# Crear botones para un formulario (dos valores, si, no)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

tengo este formulario, que quiero que al momento de ser rellenado se vea solo dos opciones a legir, algo como un interruptor, si o no; utilizando bootstrap.

```html
<form>
<div class="editor-label">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lucesuno)
</div>
   <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lucesuno)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lucesuno)
</div>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="crear" />
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: mira por favor [ask].. y cual seria el problema que tienes?

Comment: Podes usar `RadioButtonFor()` o crear un [editor template](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/extending-editor-templates-for-asp-net-mvc/) según tu necesidad..

Comment: Prueba con Bootstrap Toggle que es un plug in para Bootsrap. http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Answer (score 0):

Son botones tipo toggle. 
Existe un componente de angular material perfecto para lo que necesitas, de todas formas mira el enlace que te dejo
Estan creados varios con diferentes estilos y comportamienos
https://codepen.io/aanjulena/pen/ZLZjzV
Si te resulta util marca la respuesta como solución. Saludos